# Как определить, что input содержит только цифры?

Tags: python, строки

На вход подается строка произвольной длины и разными символами. Если в этой строке есть только цифры, переменная `error = 0`, если нет, то `error = 1`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Наверное, правильно было бы переформулировать вопрос как-то так -- `Как определить, что input содержит только цифры?`. Думаю, что число неумных минусаторов сократилось бы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```py
s = input()

try:
    int(s)
except ValueError:
    error = 1  # есть буквы
else:
    error = 0  # только цифры
```

Comment: сейчас идет кд, и через несколько минут это сделаю

Comment: осталось 4 минуты

Comment: Ничего, я подожду)

Comment: Все, поставил))

Comment: `-1` как обработает?

Comment: @АлексейР для этого нужно использовать не `try/except`, а `s.isalpha()`